# An Oil Pipeline--A Target for the Livens Flamethrower

Tags: construction, weapon-mass-destruction, materials

Ranking highly on the list of the most devastating weapons in human history is a British invention for World War I--the Livens Large Gallery Flame Projector.

[image]

It measured 56 feet long and weighed two-and-a-half tons.  The trademark of this weapon that made it so frightening is a nozzle that shot out ignited fuel to a maximum reach of 100-130 feet.

[image]

Here is the target in this worst-case scenario, a petroleum pipeline.

[image]

Let us assume, for this scenario, that some eco-terrorist group managed to get ahold of the Livens flamethrower and aimed at the pipelines.  It seems an effective strategy on paper, but will the pipeline's outer covering prove to be fireproof?  If not, will the oil burn and explode from within?

Comment: this seems more like a *defensive* weapon. Not to mention one that would do an inordinate amount of collatral damage, and needing days or weeks to set up. Monkeywrenching the pumps along the way seems like a more sensible solution

Comment: Modern flame weapons use thermobaric warheads rather than projecting burning fuel at the target, and use rockets to provide far longer range than any conceivable flamethrower.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I severely doubt it. Oil pipeline is pretty sturdy stuff, and has low leakage, since the stuff is precious. You may manage to set fire to the paint on the pipe, but you aren't going to overheat it enough to burst in a few seconds of flame: it will be cooled by the oil flowing through it. There's no air within the pipe, so the oil can't catch fire there.

A small amount of industrial explosive would be a vastly more effective weapon against an oil pipeline. That will let you breach it and spill the oil, which is then easy to ignite. It's also very much easier to transport and use than a monster flamethrower.